# Google Visualization ColorFormat Exact Match String

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to colour a text column based off an exact match? I have tried setting the from and to, to the same value but it doesn't colour the cell?

```
formatter.addRange('danger', 'danger', 'red', 'white');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high boundary, or *To* value, is *non-inclusive*

so it has to be something after `'danger'`

including a space at the end will color the cell

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'string');
    data.addColumn('number', 'number');
    data.addRow(['danger', 0]);
    data.addRow(['safe', 1000]);
    data.addRow(['unknown', 1001]);

    var formatColor = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
    formatColor.addRange('danger', 'danger ', 'white', 'red');
    formatColor.addRange(1000, 1001, 'white', 'green');
    formatColor.format(data, 0);
    formatColor.format(data, 1);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true
    });
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I want danger and 0 to get highlighted by red and green only. Can you suggest some way? Stuck in this problem for 6 hours

Comment: not sure I follow exactly, maybe post another question. but replacing the `addRange` statements above with the following, seems to do the trick...   `formatColor.addRange('danger', 'danger ', 'white', 'red');`
`formatColor.addRange(0, 1, 'white', 'green');`